# PrimeNG Chip: removeIconClass is not working and is not allowing me to replace the default ICON which is pi pi-times-circle

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am relatively new to prime NG and is still trying to figure out few things. I am stuck in a place where I want to change the default remove icon of a Prime NG chip using the Property **removeIconClass** as mentioned in the document. But It is not working and instead it keeps on showing the default icon.
Below are the two ways which I have tried and the error associated with one of them. It will really be helpful if some one from primeNG team tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
<p-chip *ngFor="let req of requirements" label="{{req.name}}" removeIconClass="pi pi-times" (onRemove)="onRemove(req.id)" [removable]="true"
            styleClass="chip-tag ntg-bg-white-bg ntg-body3 p-m-1 p-py-1 p-px-3"></p-chip>



<p-chip *ngFor="let req of requirements" label="{{req.name}}" [removeIconClass]="pi pi-times" (onRemove)="onRemove(req.id)" [removable]="true"
            styleClass="chip-tag ntg-bg-white-bg ntg-body3 p-m-1 p-py-1 p-px-3"></p-chip>
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing the square brackets around `removeIconClass`.

Comment: Yes, Has already tried that if you see in the first code sample. In That case There is no effect and the default icon only appears i.e My desired icon does not show up.

Comment: Ha, I see that...now. That is odd. Could be a bug with the component. Think about submitting an issue on the [primeng github](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng).

Comment: This got resolved. It looks like removeIconClass has been renamed to removeIcon lately. But The document at https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chip  is not updated. Kinda weird though as documents should be up to date.

Comment: I saw that in a commit when I was searching! I assumed the docs were up to date, too. Glad you got it working.